# Which data type to sort through a text file with three double values on each line?

Tags: java

```
736.0 4090.7 -128.3
4839.2 3909.7 -131.6
3063.1 1010.6 -129.3
2173.0 1250.0 -124.2
349.7 4173.1 -130.6
4755.8 3638.3 -130.2
```

**This is a sample from the text file i am using.**
The first two values represent `x/y` values and the final is a representation of a signal strength.

Which data type should I be using? I'm currently testing out an `ArrayList` but don't want to go down the wrong path.

I need to plot each `x/y` value on a 500px*500px `JFrame` and indicate it's strength using different colors.

Comment: `ArrayList` would be my best recommendation.

Comment: @3kings thanks mate.